# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-failsafe-plugin:3.0.0-M1:verify (default)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, openjdk-17

**Problem :**
I updated my JDK JAVA 17 from Java 11.
But I encounter some problem when I want to build my spring project
Here my error when I do maven install :

```
 [INFO] 
    [INFO] Results:
    [INFO] 
    [ERROR] Errors: 
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-failsafe-plugin:3.0.0-M1:verify (default) on project myapp-bo: There are test failures.
```

**What I do :**

- Update JAVA JDK to 17
- In my pom.xml :

1. Add <java.version>17</java.version>
2. Change the version of    jacoco-maven-plugin 0.8.7 (before 0.8.6)
3. Add maven-surefire-plugin and maven-failsafe-plugin : 3.0.0-M1
4. Update spring-boot-starter-parent to : 2.4.13

**[UPDATE 02-02-2022 AT 13:38]**

- When I do maven install, I haven't error : BUILD SUCCESS
- When I do run as java Program, I have some error :
  Question : What does it mean ?

> ```
> 2022-02-02 13:37:06.549 DEBUG 27549 --- [  restartedMain] Validator                                : ERROR
> ```
>
> [ModelSpecification.spec] At least one type of specification is
> required

Here my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.13</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.package.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>myapp-bo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>myapp-bo</name>
    <description>Projet myApp</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <keycloak.version>16.1.0</keycloak.version>
        <querydsl.version>4.1.3</querydsl.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-undertow</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ognl</groupId>
            <artifactId>ognl</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-email</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.flapdoodle.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.icegreen</groupId>
            <artifactId>greenmail-junit5</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.awaitility</groupId>
            <artifactId>awaitility</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-admin-client</artifactId>
            <version>16.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-scratchpad</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>1.13.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency> 
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.13.Final</version>
        </dependency> 
        <dependency> 
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
         </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
          <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId> 
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.7</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.8</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- Swagger dependency -->
 
                <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.springfox/springfox-swagger2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
                <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.springfox/springfox-swagger-ui -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.3</version>
        </dependency>
                        
                
         
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.keycloak.bom</groupId>
                <artifactId>keycloak-adapter-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${keycloak.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <release>11</release>
             </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>process</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/java</outputDirectory>
                        <processor>com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.7</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>before-unit-test-execution</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <destFile>${project.build.directory}/jacoco-output/jacoco-unit-tests.exec</destFile>
                        <propertyName>surefire.jacoco.args</propertyName>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>after-unit-test-execution</id>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <dataFile>${project.build.directory}/jacoco-output/jacoco-unit-tests.exec</dataFile>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/jacoco-unit-test-coverage-report</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>before-integration-test-execution</id>
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <destFile>${project.build.directory}/jacoco-output/jacoco-integration-tests.exec</destFile>
                        <propertyName>failsafe.jacoco.args</propertyName>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>after-integration-test-execution</id>
                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <dataFile>${project.build.directory}/jacoco-output/jacoco-integration-tests.exec</dataFile>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/jacoco-integration-test-coverage-report</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>merge-unit-and-integration</id>
                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>merge</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <fileSets>
                            <fileSet>
                                <directory>${project.build.directory}/jacoco-output/</directory>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>*.exec</include>
                                </includes>
                            </fileSet>
                        </fileSets>
                        <destFile>${project.build.directory}/jacoco-output/merged.exec</destFile>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>create-merged-report</id>
                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <dataFile>${project.build.directory}/jacoco-output/merged.exec</dataFile>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/jacoco-merged-test-coverage-report</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
             <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
            <configuration>
                <argLine>${surefire.jacoco.args}</argLine>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
             <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
            <configuration>
                <argLine>${failsafe.jacoco.args}</argLine>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        <goal>verify</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

Comment: I would strongly suggest to upgrade your Spring Boot version to at least the newest in the 2.4 range. Which would also pull-up the sure-fire etc. version but if you don't make sure you have version 3.0.0.M5 for surefire/failsafe.

Comment: I have changed maven compiler with version 3.8.1 and it's display many error so I keep maven-compiler-plugin: configuration:release:11. All the test is running, but for One controller I have this error : [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-failsafe-plugin:3.0.0-M1:verify (default) on project myref-bo: There are test failures.

Comment: Your test failed which is what the result is telling you. I nowhere said you should change your compiler version, nor do you actually need it to be in there it is already there in the parent using the `java.version` you specified in the first place.

Comment: Thanks @M. Deinum. Sorry I follow this website (https://simply-how.com/getting-started-with-java-17) who recommend to update maven-compiler-plugin to 3.8.1.

Comment: Spring Boot already manages that version so your override is pretty much useless (and the website shows 2 methods it is an OR not and AND). Also Spring Boot 2.4.0 is old use a newer version 2.4.13 (or whatever the newest is in that range) or better use something even newer and still supported.